# Update chart using BackgroundWorker ProgressChanged Event?

Tags: vb.net, charts, backgroundworker

I have a form that displays a chart and a progress bar.  Some complex calculations are undertaken by a `BackgroundWorker` component so that the form remains responsive.  The result is appended to a list and then the `ReportProgress` method is called so that the `ProgressChanged` event handler can update the progress bar (which it does).

However I'm struggling to update the chart in the same `ProgressChaned` event handler which is successfully updating the progress bar.  I assume this is possible?  I would like the chart to update after each iteration of the `BackgroundWorker`.  I can't update the chart directly from the `BackgroundWorker` since it's doing its work on a different thread.

The code in the `ProgressChanged` event handler that's trying to update the chart is as follows:

```
Me.ResultsChart.DataSource = myResultsList
With Me.ResultsChart.Series("Results")
    .XValueMember = "Iteration"
    .YValueMembers = "ObjectiveFunction"
End With
```

The `myResultsList` list is quite simple.  It is defined as `Private myResultsList As List(Of Results) = New List(Of Results)`.  The `Results` class only contains two properties: `Iteration` and `ObjectiveFunction`.

Currently, it doesn't give any errors, but the chart doesn't update until the `BackgroundWorker` task is completely done.  Should I be doing something different when I'm assigning the data to the chart or something entirely different?

Comment: In what way does it not work?  Does it get an error, or does the chart just not update?

Comment: The chart doesn't update after each iteration, but displays in full once backrground worker is complete. The background worker might be iterating away for a few minutes so I'd like to update the chart after each iteration.

Comment: Does the debugger show `myResultsList` containing any data if you put a break point in the ProgressChanged event handler?  What type of object is `myResultsList`?

Comment: Private myResultsList As List(Of Results) = New List(Of Results)

Comment: The results class only contains two properties, Iteration and ObjectiveFunction

Comment: Yes, myResultsList does contain data if I put a breakpoint in and cycle through a few iterations.  the chart displays fully and correctly at the end, the issue is how I get it to update iteratively with the backgroundworker

Answer (score 1):

I've sorted this, basically the background worker was iterating quicker than the chart could update.  So instead I'm now clearing the chart and reading the entire results list back in on a separate thread each time.  Once the full logic in the backgroundworker is built up, the issue may "self heal" as the iterations will take longer, but for now this works.